# Read file from Requests module in Python

Tags: python, r, web-services

I'm trying to create a web service using Python or R. This web service should 
be able to receive a file as an input and process it. So far i have made the API request as follow in Python:

```
import requests
with open('userdata.txt','rb') as payload:
    r = requests.post('https://localhost:8080/upload', data=payload, verify=False)
```

However, i am not sure how to setup the "/upload" web service. I have python and/or R available to process the request as it is on a server that i cant gain further access to. The overall task is to receive the file, load a machine learning algorithm, classify the text inside the file and return an answer with a score, if that changes anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you mentioned in your question is the client-side of the code. You have to choose a web-framework first. For a single controller like the one you mentioned, you could use [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/). Its so minimal and fun to use. simply `pip install cherrypy` then

```
import cherrypy

class UploadFile(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def upload(self, ufile):
        data = ufile.file.read() # Read the file you uploaded
        # Process your data

cherrypy.quickstart(UploadFile())
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!